# django 1.7 template deleted, but still loads as if it exists

Tags: django, templates

#### Question:

What do I need to do to have Django load a template from the filesystem, instead of loading from memory/cache?

#### Use case:

I am using `render_to_string()` to generate a template's HTML for use as an attachment to a `EmailMultiAlternatives`.

#### Problem:

I have made changes to the template, sent a subsequent email, yet the changes to the template are not reflected in the email. I have `print`ed the `render_to_string()` prior to sending the email and it too is not updated, so the problem exists prior to the email part.

#### Details:

I am using the default settings.TEMPLATE_LOADERS (filesystem/app_directories) for Django 1.7, have tried clearing the cache and have restarted the default development server.

If I change the filename of the template, `render_to_string()` renders the "changes."

What is even stranger is I have completely removed the template file from the filesystem, yet `render_to_string()` still renders the original template.

This is a "new problem," as I have modified templates countless times and their changes have been reflected immediately.

Comment: Sure you don't have that file somewhere else on your file system? Try check your template file locations in settings.py and review your template files in your file system.

Comment: @dan, make your comment into an answer and you'll get an acceptance!

Comment: Not really an answer but I'll add anyways. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have that file somewhere else on your file system? Try checking your template file locations in `settings.py` and review your template files in your file system.